# Something Weird in my markup. Twitter bootsrap tab not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I designed a markup and i'm trying to make a tab on bootsrap with jquery. I wrote markup code as below. Please examine why the tabs are not working? What wrong with my code. 
in javascript console it showing 
**ReferenceError: $ is not defined**

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Just Live 24</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/tv-theme.css">
<link href="css/main_pricetable.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="col-md-6">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="myTab">
  <li class="active"><a href="#home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
  <li><a href="#settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">bmnmn,b,mbn...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">.werewr..</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">.jkhk..</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">llkjlk...</div>
</div>
<script>
$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
$(this).tab('show');
})</script>

</div>
<hr>






</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably you forgot to attach http in script src attribute.

```
src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"
src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
```

As a result browser is unable to fetch scripts and is not recogizing jquery shorthand (i.e. $).

Comment: Those are just [protocol-relative URLs](http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/), which should work fine as-is, unless the page is being viewed locally via `file://`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Example of Twitter Bootstrap 3 Tabs</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="#messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
        <li><a href="#settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
    </ul>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="tab-content" style="margin-left:20px;">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">bmnmn,b,mbn...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">.werewr..</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">.jkhk..</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">llkjlk...</div>
</div>

</div>
<hr>
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7r6kgooh/

Comment: Yeah go -1 on the solution, way to go bro

Comment: SO isn't a 'write code for me' site. Add an explanation - what did OP do wrong and how did you fix it? Then you can only post the relvant code to change too..

Comment: If he reads the code he will figure it out since he will see the differences... You are very strange mister